# How to assign default value to variable if first condition failed?

Tags: elixir

I've in Ruby following expression:

```
env = opts.env || "staging"
```

How to write it in Elixir?

**EDIT:**

This expression in Elixir won't work:

```
case Repo.insert(changeset) do
  {:ok, opts} ->
    env = opts.env || "staging"
```

Error:

```
** (KeyError) key :env not found in: %Myapp.App{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded>
```

Comment: I think your Error is telling you that your opts has no "member" called env - the keyword :env is the way elixir labels that "member".  You could check using IO.inspect opts

Comment: You can use `Map.get(opts, :env, "staging")` in your simple case.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The exact same idiom works (assuming by "failed" you mean opts.env is nil):

```
iex(1)> nil || "staging"
"staging"
iex(2)> "production" || "staging"
"production"
```

Elixir, as Ruby, treats nil as a falsy value.

Comment: So I have following error when I'm trying to do this with changeset ```** (KeyError) key :env not found in: %Myapp.App{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded>...```

Comment: It is working, I had to add env field to the schema.

Answer (score 2):

To add general information regarding [structs](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/structs.html) in Elixir:

As structs do not allow accessing noexistent  keys, you are facing the `KeyError`.
Though structs are built on top of maps. By using map functions on structs you can get the expected behavior for nonexistent keys.

`Map.get(<struct>, <key>)` will return nil if the key is not defined for the struct:

```
# With "opts" being a struct without "env" key

iex> Map.get(opts, :env) || "staging"
"staging"

# Map.get/3 has the same behavior
iex> Map.get(opts, :env, "staging")
"staging"
```

Comment: or `get_in(opts, [Access.key(:env, "staging")])` which is convenient when working with deeply nested structures. More on that in docs on `Access.key`

Answer (score 1):

For sake of completeness this would also do what you want:

```
e = "production" # Setting this only because I don't have an opts.env in my app.

env = if !e, do: "staging", else: e
#"production"

e = nil

env = if !e, do: "staging", else: e
#"staging"
```